# Simplest WP7 logger

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, logging

I need the simplest logger for wp7, no network reporting or file storing. Just simple reports to the console. It should be able to work with strings, objects and formatted strings:

- SimpleLogger.WriteLine("JustLine");
- SimpleLogger.WriteLine(ObjectToBeCastedToString);
- SimpleLogger.WriteLine("Price is {0} {1}", price, currency);

Comment: Where the "question" part than? And you "answer" is not really up to SO standards - random chunk of code without explanation (ignoring the fact that you use local time instead of UTC and for whatever reason use `#if` instead of conditional attributes).

Comment: Question is "Simplest WP7 logger". Answer is not a random code, it works for me quite nice. Also, please, take a glance at the last sentence of the question. In case you miss it either, it is "improvement considerations are welcome".

Comment: I've added my comment to the post, feel free to improve it. I really suggest to use http://codereview.stackexchange.com for review first if you want to show your code. And please make "question" look like a question (don't forget to remove all text you have there now as it does not describe problem you provided solution for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class SimpleLogger
{
    private static DateTime lastLog;

    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public static void WriteLine(object value)
    {
        WriteLine((value == null) ? "(null)" : value.ToString());
    }

    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public static void WriteLine(string format)
    {
        WriteLine("{0}", format);
    }

    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public static void WriteLine(string format, params object[] values)
    {
        var formatted = String.Format(null, format, values);

        Debug.WriteLine("{0:hh:mm:ss.fff} [{1:hh:mm:ss.fff}] {2}", DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow - lastLog, formatted);
        lastLog = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

Comment: -1: The code does not compile (`NotNullAttribute` does not exist). I'd strongly recommend to properly use conditional attribute instead of `#if`.

Comment: What's the benefit of using attribute here? Compatibility? Updated.